# Invalid data in mongoDB after insert of an ISO data

Tags: jquery, mongodb, meteor, fullcalendar

I try to store a record based on a dayClick event out of the jquery fullcalendar. According to the consol log the date is provided as:
*locale: Object, _d: Date 2015-03-19T00:00:00.000Z,*  then I pass it to ce.start and ce.end, when I check the database I have 'Invalid date' as value in calevnt.start and calevent.end --- What's wrong here?

On the client:

```
Template.calendar.helpers({
options: function() {
    return {
        lang: 'de',
        dayClick:function(date,allDay,jsEvent,view){
            var ce = {};
            ce.start = date;
            ce.end = date;
            ce.color = 'red';
            ce.className = 'todo';
            ce.project = Session.get('active_project');
            ce.title = ' Jour Fixe2';
            ce.owner = Meteor.userId;
            console.log(date,allDay,jsEvent,view);
            Meteor.call('addCalEvent',ce);
        }
    }
}
});
```

On the server:

```
'addCalEvent': function (calevent) {
 if (!calevent.type) {
    calevent.type = 'milestone';
  }
  return Calevents.insert(calevent);
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
Template.calendar.helpers({
    options: function() {
        return {
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            lang: 'de',
            select: function(start, end, allDay) {
                var ce = {};
                ce.start = start.format(); // return moment date
                ce.end = end.format(); // return moment date 
                ce.color = 'red';
                ce.className = 'todo';
                ce.project = Session.get('active_project');
                ce.title = ' Jour Fixe2';
                ce.owner = Meteor.userId;
                console.log(start, end);
                Meteor.call('addCalEvent',ce);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Little update: I still can stay with the dayClick and only had to use **ce.start = date.format();** to format the date.

Comment: With this update the date is stored in the mongoDB as:   
`    "start" : "2015-03-26",`  
`    "end" : "2015-03-26",`  
to keep the current logic in the app I would need the following format:  
`"start" : ISODate("2015-03-10T23:00:00.000Z"),`  
`"end" : ISODate("2015-03-10T23:00:00.000Z"),`  
  
How can this be archived??