# How to format jquery fullcalendar date as ISODate for MongoDB?

Tags: jquery, mongodb, fullcalendar

I want to store a day which I get from the dayClick event of the fullcalendar as ISODate in a MongoDB. 
    dayClick:function(date,allDay,jsEvent,view){
            ce.start = date;
            alert('Clicked on: ' + ce.start + '--' + date.format());
    })
The result is:

> 1425427200000--2015-03-04

but I need in mongo:

> "start" : ISODate("2015-03-27T23:00:00.000Z")

What would be the correct formating rule.
ca.start = date.?????

---

EDIT

I have found this here on mongodb.org but I can not really make use of it. The provided answers always return 
"start" : "ISODate(\"2015-03-18T14:35:41.751Z\")",
but I need 
"start" : ISODate("2015-03-12T23:00:00.000Z"),

Maybe an expert can get more out of the following:

The mongo shell wrap objects of Date type with the ISODate helper; however, the objects remain of type Date.

The following example uses both the new Date() constructor and the ISODate() constructor to return Date objects.

var myDate = new Date();
var myDateInitUsingISODateWrapper = ISODate();

You can use the new operator with the ISODate() constructor as well.

To print the value of the variable, type the variable name in the shell, as in the following:

myDate

The result is the Date value of myDate wrapped in the ISODate() helper:

ISODate("2012-12-19T06:01:17.171Z")

Comment: I'm not super familiar with mongo, are you accessing it through nodejs?

Comment: And could you add the code responsible for adding this date to the DB if my edited answer doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fullcalendar uses [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) for it's dates.

You can [format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) them however you want:

```
var formatstring = "YYYY-MM-DD";
date.format(formatstring);
```

For ISO format see my answer here: [Convert system date to ISO format using momentjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28277272/convert-system-date-to-iso-format-using-momentjs/28287209#28287209)

```
moment().utc().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]");
//or
moment().utc().format('[ISODate("]YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS[Z")]');
```

Edit:

For some reason I assumed you needed a string... I think you actually just need a JS date object inside another object:

```
var obj = {
    start: moment().toDate()
};
//or
var start = moment().toDate();
```

Edit again:

I looked at your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117863/invalid-data-in-mongodb-after-insert-of-an-iso-data) and got some more context. You likely want:

```
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
            var ce = {};
            ce.start = start.toDate();
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) by doing something like this

`var ISODate = new Date(date).toISOString();`

So your dayClick would look like this

```
dayClick: function(date, allday, e, view){
   var ISODate = new Date(date).toISOString();
   console.log('ISODate("'+ISODate+'")');
}
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h9cC6/1655/)

Comment: Thank, but doing so I end up with
`    "start" : "2015-03-28T00:00:00.000Z"`
`    "end" : "2015-03-28T00:00:00.000Z"`
in the mongoDB what is almost ok, but I ned ISODate(.. to cover the existing logic is there a futher formating command or is this string manipulation?

Comment: I'm not sure how mongodb takes date, but if you want it exactly like that, then yes, it would just be a string manipulation. I updated my answer accordingly